# How to detect user scrolll on the scrollview

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiscrollview, scrollview

i want to detect when the user scroll on the scrollview and above a certain scroll item show up a button, i wrote this code on my up looking online some example but there is no printout on the change of scrollID, why??

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
        ForEach(group) { g in
            NavigationLink {
                Text("Details")
            } label: {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "tv") // Replace with actual images
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: reader.size.width/3, height: 50)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                    Text("List")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
            }
        }
    }
    .scrollTargetLayout()
}
.scrollPosition(id: $scrollID)
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: To check if a user scroll to a certain item then add onAppear to view for this item. To scroll titan item add id to the view you want to be able to scroll to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example, improvising the parts that were missing.

It works for me. The IDs of the items in the first column of the `LazyVGrid` are printed when the grid is scrolled. So the problem may be somewhere in the code you didn't post.

Here is the updated (working) example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    struct Group: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
    }

    let columns = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
    let group: [Group]
    @State private var scrollID: Group.ID?

    init() {
        var groups = [Group]()
        for i in 0..<100 {
            groups.append(Group())
        }
        self.group = groups
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                    ForEach(group) { g in
                        NavigationLink {
                            Text("Details")
                        } label: {
                            VStack {
                                Image(systemName: "tv") // Replace with actual images
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: reader.size.width/3, height: 50)
                                    .padding()
                                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                Text("\(g.id)") // "List"
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                            }
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollPosition(id: $scrollID)
            .onChange(of: scrollID) { oldVal, newVal in
                print("\(String(describing: newVal))")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologize, for the non reproducable code, i found the error on my code, was " @State private var scrollID: Group.ID?" i didt set correct